# How can limit input in EditText?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I have got a `EditText`.
I only  want input characters: `a->z,A->Z,0->9 and @.#,-,_`
How can limit key on keyboard input in `EditText`?

Comment: In your EditText field in .xml you can set "android:inputType=..." to limit the input. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for further Information about various input types. But I don't think that there is an input type for your purpose. So you have to do it programattically and check each character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<EditText 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:inputType="text"
  android:digits="0123456789......yourcharcters"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code snipset to check it with a regex:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText );
if( !yourEditText.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") ); // This regex matches only letters
  yourEditText.setError( "Error on text, only a->z,A->Z" );
```

You can add this cose on an event...for example on a button click.

For the regex that you want you can find it on internet, or try to write your one and test it on this site:
[Regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first idea coming to my head is to create a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and validate every character inputed by user, using regex construction.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 3;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
et.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

If you do not find good combination then implement your own listener and validate text each time it is changed.